# SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed") on django

Tags: python, django, smtplib

In my Django application, I'm trying to send emails via SMTP. This is my configuration in the settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your_password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your_email@gmail.com'
```

However, I'm encountering an exception that says `SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")`, and I'm not sure why. I've tried changing the backend and the port, but it still doesn't work. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if you get more info on the error:

```
import smtplib

username = "some.email@gmail.com"
password = r"your_actual_password"

s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
s.set_debuglevel(1)
s.login(username, password)
s.quit()
```